# Data Table Table Tools Button not displaying in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, datatables

I am using data table table  tool option (http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/). It works fine on Firefox and Crome but not working in IE. Even the button of exporting type is not showing. The  other things of data table works fine in IE. I have included the following line

```
 var table = $('#dtable').DataTable({

        "paging": false,

        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
    });
```

the following figure showing firefox result
[image]

IE result:[image]

i can not figure out the issue.

Comment: Which version of ie and Jquery you are using? DId you check the console?

Comment: jquery:jquery-1.8.0.min.js  and IE 11 and I have checked the console no error showing @LogicalForhad

Comment: The problem in this question is not reproduceable. And you have left something out in the `DataTable()` initialization. Can you set up a fiddle where the problem exists?

Comment: Hi there, did you find the answer to this, as I have the same issue.

Comment: Hello. I have the same question. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is because table tools uses Adobe Flash Player. I was having same problem. After installing Adobe Flash Player in Internet Explorer I get all the buttons.(Have to admit IE is a headache).